# What's the difference between OneToOne and Subclassing a model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

For example:

```
class Subdomain(Site):
    #fields here
```

and

```
class Subdomain(models.Model):
    site = models.OneToOne(Site)
    #fields here
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Models with a `OneToOne` have an independent PK; submodels always use the PK of their supermodel.

Comment: What is the semantic difference between the two? When would you use one over the other?